# sources.list & sources.list.d in /etc/apt

Tags: apt, software-sources

I could find that there is a `sources.list` file as well as a `sources.list.d` directory in the `/etc/apt` directory. If I am not wrong, both are used to set up the deb files for the packages we need to include.

Then what is the difference between the two?